# on click smooth animate width

Tags: jquery, css

Seen a few posts but nothing that answers it directly and simply. I want to click a button, and the div next to it animates smoothly the width to make the div bigger, then returns to original width when clicked again please.

Comment: `"Seen a few posts..."`, then you must've seen how posts are supposed to be written.

Comment: Like this? https://jqueryui.com/animate/

Comment: What have you done so far?  Where is your code? At which point do you have an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you will need `HTML`, `CSS`, `JS`.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/0hm7kz1o/) **(No jQuery)**.
Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/0hm7kz1o/1/) **(with jQuery)**

Here is the snippet **(No jQuery)**.

```js
var status = 0;

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', resize);

function resize() {
  if (status == 0) {
    document.getElementById('scene').className = 'grow';
    status = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('scene').className = 'normal';
    status = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
#scene {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.normal {
  width: 200px;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}
.grow {
  width: 400px;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
<input id='button' type='button' value='Resize DIV' />
<br>
<div id='scene' class='normal'></div>
```

Here  is the snippet **(with jQuery)**.

```js
var status = 0;

$('#button').click(function() {
  if (status == 0) {
    $('#scene').removeClass("normal");
    $('#scene').addClass("grow");
    status = 1;
  } else {
    $('#scene').removeClass("grow");
    $('#scene').addClass("normal");
    status = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
#scene {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.normal {
  width: 200px;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}
.grow {
  width: 400px;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='button' type='button' value='Resize DIV' />
<br>
<div id='scene' class='normal'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! yes it does. appreciate you taking the time to show me this, instead of just trying to add condescending comments.

Answer (score 2):

Check this Fiddle,
https://jsfiddle.net/s29007nL/

HTML:

```
<div id="button">Click me</div>
<br/>
<div id="big">soon bigger</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    font-family:Verdana;
}
#button {
    background:lightgreen;
    height:20px;         width:100px;
    border-radius:10px;  text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#big{
    background:purple;
    height:50px;        width:100px;
    text-align:center;  line-height:50px;
    color:#fff;
}
.ready_to_big {    
    animation-name: big_it;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}


@keyframes big_it {
    from {width:100px;} to {width:400px;}
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', bigTheDiv);

function bigTheDiv(){
    document.getElementById("big").className = "ready_to_big";
    setTimeout(function(){ 
           document.getElementById("big").className = "";
     },1000);    
}
```

Improvements can be done based on what you aim finally.